# What's the difference between creating a new instance with "new() and ".StartNew()"?

Tags: c#, .net, system.diagnostics, stopwatch

Coming from my "answer" to question ["Stopwatch in a Task seems to be additive across all tasks, want to measure just task interval"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16259019/200449)

What are the possible differences between creating a new [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) instance as:

```
Stopwatch timer = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
```

with

```
Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
timer.Start();
```

Implied subquestion:
Why was `StartNew()` method provided?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`StartNew`, create new instance of the stop watch and starts it as well.

Simple `new` is Stopwatch instantiation only. It doesn't start the Stopwatch.

For your current code where you are creating a new instance and calling `Start`,  there shouldn't be any difference to `Stopwatch.StartNew()`

See [Stopwatch.StartNew() - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.startnew.aspx)

> This method is **equivalent** to calling the Stopwatch constructor and
>   then calling Start on the new instance.

`StartNew` provides an easier way to create and start Stopwatch in one step.

Answer (score 5):

> Why was StartNew() method provided?

It's a simpler alternative.  `StartNew` is effectively the same as allocating a new stop watch and starting it instantly.

Since that's a very common use case, the `StartNew` factory method just simplifies and shortens the API, and reduces the code required to use a stopwatch.

Answer (score 1):

It **initializes a new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch instance and sets the elapsed time property to zero**, and starts measuring elapsed time

and save the one line code to implicitly calling **Start()** method