# Calculate elapsed bundle installer execution time

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bundle, bootstrapper, execution-time

Is there any way to calculate elapsed execution time for the bundle installer? I have three MSIs which are chained in a single bundle installer. I want to get the total execution time for all the MSI installers which I will use to log in a text file (log file).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

***Custom Bootstrapper Application?***: Strange that this is not already included in the bootstrapper. Are you using the [WiX Standard Bootstrapper Application](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/wixstdba/) or are you using a [Custom Bootstrapper Application](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/ba/%C2%A8)? I have never had the time to create a proper custom bootstrapper application, but I suppose you could use a simple StopWatch if you use a .NET application? Sounds too simplistic, but maybe worth a try.

**UPDATE**: replaced the compressed mockup with a small ad-hoc application sample.

```c#
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace StopWatchTester
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();

            Thread.Sleep(4000); // stuff happens here

            stopwatch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
            Console.ReadLine(); // keep console open
        }
    }
}
```

***Silent Burn Bundle Install?***: I suppose you could kick off the whole `setup.exe` Burn bundle in quiet mode from your own executable and use the above code to time the execution? [**Running Burn-driven installer in quiet mode (command line parameters)**](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Running-Burn-driven-installer-in-quiet-mode-command-line-parameters-td5913001.html).

---

- [What's the difference between creating a new instance with "new() and ".StartNew()"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259437/whats-the-difference-between-creating-a-new-instance-with-new-and-startnew)